# Query in SQL from single table

Tags: sql

I have a table with field `Document Type`. I want those records of `Customer` whose `Sum(Amount)` of `Document Type` `4` - `Sum(Amount)` of `Document type` `6` > `0` then those records of that `Customer` whose `Document Type` in `(4,6)` should be displayed.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that your Table name is TableA and Customer column name is CustomerID.

We can achieve the requirement by below SQL logic.

```
   select x.* from TableA x

    join 

    (select * from 
    (select dt4.customerID, sum_amount_dt4-sum_amount_dt6 as dt4minusdt6
    from 
    (select CustomerID,sum(Amount) as sum_amount_dt4 from TableA a
    where a.Docutype=4)dt4
    join
    (select CustomerID,sum(Amount) as sum_amount_dt6 from TableA a
    where a.Docutype=6)dt6
    on dt4.customerID=dt6.customerID
    )dt46
    where dt46.dt4minusdt6>0 ) y

on x.customerID=y.customerID
```

Comment: Hi , I have only 1 table . First i want to get those Customers whose document type is 5 and the check  sum(Amount) of document type 5 of that customer - Sum(Amount) of document Type 4 = 0 . if condition is satisfied then i want to display all records of that Customer.